# How can I create a white arrow with a grey border?

Tags: html, css

Him

I am trying to create an arrow pointing left but with a grey border.

So far I just have a grey arrow.

Would anyone have an idea on how I can do that?

I have attached a picture of what i mean.

Thank you in advance!

```
.tri {

    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px;

}

.tri{
    border-color: transparent #ccc transparent  transparent;

}


<div class="tri"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: This any help? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below:

```css
.box {  
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 100px;
  position: realtive;
  
  }

.box:after, .box:before {
  content: "\f0d9";
  font-family: fontAwesome;;
  top: 40%;
  left: -12px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: gray;
  position: relative;
  
  
  }

 .box:after {
   left: -23px;
   color: white;
   
   }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="box"></div>
```